# Unexpected shutdown with a "Power key pressed." log

Tags: linux, centos, shutdown

My Supermicro blade server shut itself down with the following logs. What could be the reason? (AFIK no one has touched it!)

- CPU usage was about 50% in the few hours before the incident.
- This issue had happened a few time in the past few weeks, all were when the was a similar load on the system.
- There is no entry of high temperature (or anything else) in the BIOS event log.
- There is no event registered in the IPMI log
- CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804, kernel 3.10.0-862.6.3.el7.x86_64

```
09:04:30 hostname ***some event***
09:30:52 hostname systemd-logind: Power key pressed.
09:30:52 hostname systemd-logind: Power key pressed.
09:30:52 hostname systemd-logind: Powering Off...
09:30:52 hostname systemd-logind: System is powering down.
09:30:52 hostname systemd-logind: Powering Off...
09:30:52 hostname systemd-logind: System is powering down.
09:30:52 hostname systemd: Stopping Authorization Manager...
09:30:52 hostname systemd: Stopping Authorization Manager...
```

Comment: Did someone press the power key?

Comment: That is not a title, please fix. (I will continue reading when you have done this.)

Comment: Does the blade have a ILO or system management with logs that are independent of the OS?

Comment: The post is not explicit when does it happen, and how many times.

Comment: A faulty power supply is one of the simplest explanations.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I hope not! I want to know if this message could have been caused by a non-external entity before asking for security camera check!

Comment: @Satō Katsura It is possibility. The power supply is a redundant power supply of 4 modules shared between more than a dozen nodes and none of them registered any failure at the same time. That being said, there might be an issue in the power circuit of the this particular node. However, would a power supply issue cause those log messages?

Comment: @thebtm yes, the server has IPMI and ipmi event log did not register any event.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro This issue had happened a few time in the past few weeks, all were when the was a similar load on the system.

Answer (score 10):

The most obvious answer is, of course, that someone pushed the power button. Possibly accidentally — e.g., if the power button is unfortunately sensitive and someone bumped it slightly while walking by. This can also happen with a failing power button (e.g., springs have worn out). Accidental power button presses can be helped by fashioning some sort of [Molly guard](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/molly-guard.html) to install over the power button.

Asking for a graceful shutdown from, e.g., IPMI will often also register as power button pressed.

Another possibility is (electrical) noise making the system *think* the power button has been pressed. Make sure the wires to the power button are firmly seated on the board (and the switch, if not soldered) and check cable routing to make sure the wires are away from anything with large/variable power consumption.

If nothing else works, you can edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and change `HandlePowerKey` to `ignore` (then restart systemd-logind). That should stop the system from shutting down, but it does mean that you won't be able to use the power button to initiate a clean shutdown (the hold-for-4-seconds unclean shutdown, if any, can't be disabled via systemd as it's done by the system firmware).

Comment: Yeah, faulty button or someone is pressing it, cat or cleaning lady.

Comment: Thank you derobert. I will start testing from the the last item, setting `HandlePowerKey` to `ignore`. _If_ that solves the issue, what would it mean!?

Comment: @user1507435 doesn't really tell you much, that's just configuring the system to ignore the power button press its detecting.

Comment: After setting `HandlePowerKey` to `ignore`, the server shutdown, after a week, without any error in the syslog or any event in the ipmi log.

The poweroff button is very hard to reach, so I can safely skip trying a Molly guard. 

If this shutdown is is because of a CPU getting too hot, should I expect to see an event logged somewhere?

Comment: @user1507435 was it a clean shutdown? If overheating caused a clean shutdown, I'd expect logs about it. If it was just power cut off, then maybe not. Do you have some reason to suspect overheating? I'd expect a Supermicro server to be well-enough engineered so that absent a few dead fans / clogged heat sinks / running in 100°F data center / etc. it wouldn't overheat. You should be able to watch the temperatures via IPMI.

Comment: Thank you, derobert. No, it was not a clean shutdown, as there was no log in the syslog.
The only reason I suspect overheating is that almost every time the shutdown happened there was a cpu intensive job running on the system (on average ~70% cpu usage). I guess the next course of action would be opening up the server and check if everything visually looks fine.

Comment: @user1507435 yeah, that and use the IPMI utilities (e.g., Supermicro's IPMIView if nothing else) to check if the fans are spinning, temperatures are normal, etc. High load is also when you'd expect, e.g., an inadequate power supply to fail. Or marginal capacitors. Or...